# Retrieve data from json restful web service to jquery using $.each()

Tags: jquery

I have this code on my restful web service. it returns list which outputs this

```
[{"InventoryName":"290.000000"},{"InventoryName":"80.000000"},{"InventoryName":"50.000000"}]
```

My question is how can i retrieve it using `jquery.each()`

Can you give a code snippet for this one?? THANK YOU

```
        List<Inventory> IService1.GetInventory()
    {
        List<Inventory> list = new List<Inventory>();using (SqlConnection testconn = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            if(testconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                testconn.Open();
            }

            using(SqlCommand testcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from inventoryitem",testconn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = testcmd.ExecuteReader();
                while( reader.Read())
                {
                    Inventory testObj = new Inventory();
                    testObj.InventoryName = reader["StandardCost"].ToString();
                    list.Add(testObj);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2)

Don't use `$.each`, it's super slow. `for (var i = 0, len = list.length)` is the fastest

```
$.getJSON('http://somesite.com/get/json', function(json) {
    for(var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) {
        alert(json[i]['InventoryName']);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.each()` is a lot faster than your `for` loop and even faster is: `for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) { alert(json[i].InventoryName) }`. Here is a JSPerf to demonstrate the difference in speed: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Comment: Oh crap, I wish I knew about this earlier. `$.each()` runs a bit slower than my `for` loop in that test though.

Comment: Your type of `for` loop is so slow you can barely see it on the graph. You're using `for( in )` and `for (var i = 0, len = list.length)` is the fastest.

Comment: i have this code.

$.ajax( {
      url: 'http://10.0.2.2:4442/Service1.svc/GetInventory',
   type: "GET",
   dataType:'jsonp',
   ProcessData:false,
   //method:"GetCustomer",
   method:"GetInventory",

      success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                    ServiceSucceeded(msg);
   }
   
    });
    }
    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { alert(result[i].InventoryName); }
                }

Doesn't work.

Comment: `ProcessData:false` should be removed, that's stopping it from parsing the returned JSON to a javascript object